# difference between gzip and gzip, deflate

Tags: encoding, compression, gzip, deflate, http-accept-encoding

I want to know what is the difference when I add `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` in request header and when I only add `Accept-Encoding: gzip`.

Because in response header I could see `Content-Encoding : gzip` only every time and the compression percentage is also same.

And which one is the best practice to use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388595/why-use-deflate-instead-of-gzip-for-text-files-served-by-apache, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883841/why-do-real-world-servers-prefer-gzip-over-deflate-encoding, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225136/http-what-is-the-preferred-accept-encoding-for-gzip-deflate, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.4

Comment: And see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9186091/1180620). Bottom line: just accept gzip.