# Specify multiple (gzip + brotli) httpCompression schemes in IIS7/8/8.5 and prioritise brotli

Tags: iis, http-headers, gzip, http-compression, brotli

I'm trying to get the new [Brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) compression scheme working in IIS using "[Brotli compression module for Microsoft IIS](https://www.iispeed.com/pagespeed/products/iisbrotli)" by [iisspeed.com](https://www.iispeed.com/pagespeed/products/iisbrotli).

The Brotli compression module itself works fine if I change the `<httpCompression>` config section in `applicationHost.config` to **only** have the Brotli module.

## The problem is that I want to have *both* gzip and Brotli, and prefer Brotli

The documentation on iisspeed.com says to do this:

```
<httpCompression directory="path\to\temp\folder" minFileSizeForComp="50">
        <scheme name="br" dll="path\to\iisbrotli.dll" />
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        ...
</httpCompression>
```

However I have discovered that this does not work.

The browser (Chrome in this example) sends the following `accept-encoding` header:

`accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br`

This means the browser can accept Brotli encoding `br` as well as `gzip`. **I want IIS to prefer `br` over `gzip` but there doesn't appear to be a way to prioritise each `<scheme>` element in the config**. I've tried changing the order in the .config file but it has no effect.

IIS always uses `gzip` even though `br` is supported and would be preferred because it's a smaller file size.

I have scoured Google to find that there used to be a priority setting for each compression scheme in IIS 6 but it seems to have been removed in IIS7+.

It's called `HcPriority` and went into the IIS6 metabase XML file.

See the following links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525366(v=vs.90).aspx

https://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/changes-to-compression-in-iis7

https://forums.iis.net/t/1150520.aspx

### Is there anything I can do for IIS7+ to tell IIS to prefer `br` over `gzip` if the client accepts it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears the Brotli module you referenced requires a paid license, so I haven't tried it, but I encountered a similar issue with my own [open source Brotli plugin for IIS](https://github.com/saucecontrol/BrotliIIS).

As you pointed out, current browsers advertise Brotli support after `gzip` and `deflate` in the `Accept-Encoding` header.

The [HTTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.4) gives no specific guidance on how to choose from many `Accept-Encoding` values with the same priority, so it would be acceptable to return `br` content to those clients.  However, it appears IIS always chooses the first one (left to right) that matches one of its configured compression schemes.

If you wish to leave both schemes enabled, you can modify the `Accept-Encoding` header value on requests as they enter your IIS pipeline.  The [IIS URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) can do this with a simple rule.

The `Accept-Encoding` header is represented by the `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING` Server Variable in the IIS pipeline, and you can modify it before it reaches the Compression Module(s).  Here is a sample configuration:

```
<rewrite>
    <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" />
    </allowedServerVariables>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Prioritize Brotli">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="\bbr(?!;q=0)\b" />
            </conditions>
            <serverVariables>
                <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="br" />
            </serverVariables>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The rule above looks for the string `br` (surrounded by word boundaries -- and not immediately followed by `;q=0`) in the `Accept-Encoding` header and re-writes it to be just plain `br`, giving IIS only one choice.

Note that the default URL Rewrite configuration does not allow modification of the `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING` variable.  The `allowedServerVariables` element overrides that restriction and must be configured in `applicationHost.config`.  The rewrite rule can then be defined at any level in the config hierarchy, although it probably makes sense to make it global.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because I think it's the most elegant solution that would, in theory, work for any other type of plugin or module. It's a universal solution. Thanks.

Comment: Do I need to put that entry in applicationHost.config file?

Comment: That's the most simple solution.  At a minimum, the `allowedServerVariables` config has to go in applicationHost.config. The `rules` can be defined per site or folder in web.config if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

From your second link (emphases mine):

> HcPriority is removed as scheme to use when multiple ones appear in Accept-Encoding header of request is **picked depending on scheme which is appear first** in Accept-Encoding header (assuming no q factor). **This is as per HTTP specs**.

Also discussed here: [HTTP: What is the preferred Accept-Encoding for “gzip,deflate”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225136/http-what-is-the-preferred-accept-encoding-for-gzip-deflate)

If you make make the same request with `Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate`, via an HTTP client that allows you to manually set the request headers (e.g. [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)) or a browser extension that allows you to change the request headers (e.g. [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj) for Chrome), you should see the response encoded with Brotli even when gzip and/or deflate are available.

EDIT: I was able to get the Brotli module to work as desired (i.e. use Brotli encoding when it is tied for the most-preferred regardless of ordering in Accept-Encoding) by [registering it as a global native module](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/globalmodules/add) and ordering it before both the dynamic and static compression modules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it doesn't really answer my question which is how to get the *web server* to decide the preference (without manual coding a solution), rather than the browser. Perhaps it's not possible but I will wait to see if anyone has any bright ideas.

Comment: I edited to my answer to reflect an alternative (and successful) way of achieving what you want--hope it helps.